# What does it mean "to make someone a card"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> During the Hats’ War, Tsarina Elizabeth of Russia, for propaganda
> reasons, had promised Finland independent statehood, a preposterous
> notion but one which made Finland an intriguing card in the ensuing
> diplomatic games.
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

I searched throught all definitions of "card" in Cambridge Dictionary but haven't found any definition that fits in the sentence above?

My version is: By promisin independent statehood, Elizabeth made Finland a tool for herself?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

> an intriguing **card** in the ensuing **diplomatic games**

The "card" is used as a metaphor; you play a game with cards, and in order to have a strong hand = power, you need a good hand (cards).

If a politician running for election played (for example) the “inflation card”, accusing the opposition of being responsible for the current dire economic situation, that politician would be preying on people's fears and distrust in the future.

In English if we say  "to make someone a card" that would mean actually making a physical card such as a birthday or Christmas one to give to someone. In politics, especially, one **plays the XYZ card**.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is sort of right.

The idea of establishing Finland as a state independent of Sweden was being used for purposes of furthering Russia’s diplomacy. International politics is metaphorically compared to a game of cards, and the idea of separating Finland from Sweden is being compared to one of the cards being played.

Comment: Related to the idea of a 'political football', that is, a matter that the protagonists don't much care about, but which is convenient or useful as a subject for argument.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. You can kick it here, kick it there.